# Retrieving/modifying highest & lowest values in k/v pair map?

Tags: java, dictionary

So I have encountered the situation where I have a k/v map of destination to quantity, i.e. {San Francisco -> 10}, and I want to retrieve the k/v pair with the highest or lowest value, and then after retrieving it, I want to modify the value. TreeMap obviously has this functionality, but for the keys, not the values. Are there any packages or other ways to achieve this functionality? Thanks.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use BiMap from google guava.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want values to be unique. It is possible that two unique destinations have the same quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Key/value maps are inherently unordered in most implementations (because they are implemented using hash tables). You'd need to iterate over all the values to determine the maximum. You should consider using a tuple with both the key and value, and then insert the tuple in a data structure that supports ordering.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah I thought of that; the thing is, I still want to be able to retrieve the quantity associated with a destination in efficient time; a map makes it easy for me to add new destinations and update existing ones.

Comment: There isn't much of a choice here. You can either use a map, and iterate over the values to find the extremes, or you can use my suggested answer, and lose the quick lookup by key name. Pick one to use now, optimize for performance later when it's necessary (which will require a non-standard data structure). I'd suggest iterating over the map values--it's probably faster than you'd expect.